# Converting JSON to Pandas Dataframe Text Issue

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, unicode

I am trying to load information from a HTTP request and store it as a JSON file:
here is how I am loading the data:

```
try:
    response = requests.get(url)
except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as e:
    print("ConnectionError:", e)
try:
    data = json.loads(response.text)
except JSONDecodeError:
    if "Bad Gateway" in response.text:
        print("Bad Gateway, sleeping.")
    else:
        print("JSONDecodeError, data not loaded")
if data and data["response"]["status"] == 200:
    for m in data["messages"]:
        record = {}           
        record["id"] = m["id"]
        record["text"] = m["body"]
        tweets.append(record)
```

tweets is a list of dictionaries containing all the information I got from the HTTP request.
I then save the list of dictionaries as a JSON file like this:

```
    fileName = "stuff/{}/{}.json".format(symbol, Id)
    with open(fileName, "w",encoding="utf-8") as f:
        json.dump(tweets, f,ensure_ascii=False)
```

I try to load the JSON as a dataframe like this:

```
with open('thefile.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
```

```
df = pd.read_json(json.dumps(data), orient='records')
```

The text in my JSON file looks like this:

"i felt awful to not cash out the 145 puts on Thursday open"

When I check my dataframe ( df.head() ) the text looks like this:

"ℎℎ145ℎ"

I am using jupyter notebook to view the data

I tried converting the dataframe to a Numpy array ( a = df["text"].values ) and when I printed out the text it looked fine.

What I am asking:

Can some explain why is this? Is there a problem with my data or does df.head() just print out some data in a weird style?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Good morning friend, if you got the request and add it to a dictionary at that point ok. Following the step, since you are using pandas to read the file, before saving use pandas to save as json,

```py
.to_json()
```

Use whichever guide you think is best,

- ‘split’ : dict like {‘index’ -> [index], ‘columns’ -> [columns], ‘data’ -> [values]}
- ‘records’ : list like [{column -> value}, … , {column -> value}]
- ‘index’ : dict like {index -> {column -> value}}
- ‘columns’ : dict like {column -> {index -> value}}
- ‘values’ : just the values array
- ‘table’ : dict like {‘schema’: {schema}, ‘data’: {data}}

Recommendation if using index being date, use "index" orientation. The others may bring data type differences in the response.

In that case it might be useful to convert to pandas and then to json. Makes it easy to maintain the data type. In addition to using less json lib. It can bring incompatibility for whatever you are working on.

references:

[Pandas to json](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html?highlight=to_json)
[Pandas read json](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html?highlight=read%20json#pandas.read_json)

Comment: This reaction is about as cryptic as the question to which it is posted as an answer.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).